# How can I find the same words in an array?

Tags: arrays, c, string, loops

I have a program that needs to count the number of first words in an array **finalArr[]**.
To do this, I separately write the first word to an array **distArr[]**. Then I compare the elements of the **finalArr[]** array with the elements of the **distArr[]** array. But final result is incorrect. For example, I have string "qwe qwe qwe" in **finalArr[]**, and correct result must be "3".

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void main(void)
{
    char finalArr[100];
    char src;
    int i = 0;

    printf("Enter a string: ");
    // fill the array
    while ((src = getchar()) != '\n' && i < 99)
    {
        finalArr[i] = src;
        i++;
    }
    finalArr[i] = '\0';
    printf("Result is: %s\n", finalArr); // output array

    // writing first word to distArr[]
    char distArr[100];
    int j = 0;
    for (j = 0; j < strlen(finalArr); j++)
    {
        distArr[j] = finalArr[j];
        if (finalArr[j] == ' ')
        {
            break;
        }
    }
    distArr[j] = '\0';
    printf("Dist array: %s\n", distArr);
    printf("%c", distArr[0]);

    // Compare the first word with all elements of the array finalArr[]
    int count = 0;
    int d;
    for (int k = 0; k < strlen(finalArr); k++) {
        if (finalArr[k] == ' ') {
            k++;
        }
        for(int d = k; d < strlen(distArr); d++) {
        if (distArr[d] == finalArr[d]) {
            count++;
            }
        }
    }
    printf("Count: %d", count);
}
```

**preferably, use one-dimensional arrays without strtok**

Comment: Have a look at `strcmp`, part of `string.h`. If you pass it two strings it should return `0` if the strings are equal.

Comment: What about `strstr( ptr_entire_string , keyword )` plus maintaining internal index pointer moving forward for each occurrence and then count the number of moves ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this could work:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    const char delim [] = " ";
    char finalArr [] = "qwe qwe qwe";
    char distArr [] = "qwe";
    int count = 0;
    
    char *ptr = strtok(finalArr, delim);

    while(ptr != NULL)
    {
        if (!strcmp(ptr,distArr))
            count++; //strings match
        ptr = strtok(NULL, delim);
    }
    
    printf("Result:%d",count);

    return 0;
}
```

This outputs:
`Result:3`